# Git Commands for Collaboration

Tags: git, shell, command-line, command-prompt

I'm learning basics of Git, but I can't grasp one concept. I went through major tutorials on YouTube, Github, Attlasian, Gitguys and Git-SCM. Unfortunately those tutorials are written by programmers who aren't teachers.

**Here is the thing:**

I want to contribute to an existing repo (unit testing).
But I'm only allowed to do so in a separate branch that I also have to create.

What Git commands do I need to download this project, add my code, create a separate branch, upload project with my code?

PS. For your convenience -

- name of the new branch "feature/unit-tests-from-z"
- link to the repo "https://link.git"
- name of the current branch "mainBranch"

Comment: `git clone ...`, `git checkout -b feature/unit-tests-from-z`, do work, `git add`/`git commit`, `git push`

Comment: Have you considered asking the people who own the repo in question?

Comment: Is the repo in question on GitHub? Do you have a GitHub account?

Comment: no, its on Stash. I also want to avoid any GUI apps since they bring even more confusion. Why have them if we still need to use terminal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`master` is probably the main branch, so here are the steps:

1- clone the repo:

```
git clone git_repo_url
```

2- make sure it is updated with the master:

```
git pull origin master
```

3- make a new branch based on the master:

```
git checkout -b your_new_branch
```

4- make your changes and commit it (please note it is not the best option, as you won't review your changes - It will commit everything - There are many [tutorials](http://johnkary.net/blog/git-add-p-the-most-powerful-git-feature-youre-not-using-yet/) on how to use `git add -p`):

```
git add --all
git commit -am "describe your changes"
```

5- push your changes:

```
git push origin your_new_branch
```

6- Go to github/gitlab/gitbucket/... and create a merger request (or pull request)

UPDATE:

If you want to make changes in the code you need the updated code right?
Usually the main branch is called `master`(the code that is in production).
You will create a new branch from the `master` (or from the `mainBranch`, if it is the case), so you will have an updated version of the code in a branch with different name (`your_new_branch` in my example).
In this way you can change the code and commit your changes to this new branch.    All the commands is written in the terminal. When you finish your work, you will have the `your_new_branch` different from `mainBranch`.
Then someone from your team can download your branch and merge the changes.

I have explained below.... I hope it is clear...

```
git clone git_repo_url            #clone the code
git co mainBranch                 #go to branch that have the code you need to change
git pull origin mainBranch        #make sure the local code is update with the remote branch
git checkout -b your_new_branch   #make a new branch based on the mainBranch
#at this point the code is identical in both branches( mainBranch and your_new_branch)
git add --all                     #add all the files you have changed to be commited
git commit -am "message"          #write your commit message to explain what you have changed
git push origin your_new_branch   #send your branch to the repo
```

In this way, someone from your team will be able to download your branch and merge it to the `mainBranch`:

```
git co your_new_branch            #go to your branch
git pull origin your_new_branch   #get the code
git diff mainBranch               #view the difference between branches
git co mainBranch                 #go back to the mainBranch
git merge your_new_branch         #merge your changes into the mainBranch
```

Comment: `git commit -am "describe your changes"` is the *worst* way of committing changes, you should never, ever do that. `git add -p`, followed by `git commit`. Take a second and think critically about what you're doing before you break something.

Comment: I completely agree with @meagar. The staging area is very useful; it shouldn't be skipped. Unfortunately, too many Git tutorials introduce `git commit -am "..."` much too early, which comforts learners into thinking that using this command willy-nilly is fine.

Comment: I agree, but...... he is facing difficulties to learn git, so I believe explaining how to choose the files to be committed is not the best option in this case

Comment: Thanks @gabrielhilal for your answer. Not surprisingly, I'm still a little confused. 2 questions: What is "the main branch `main`? Did you mean "mainBranch"? Because i my case, main repo has 2 branches, official one and one for developers. I need to clone the one for developers (i called it "mainBranch" here). And the last step about github - can you write it in terminal commands? My case - it is not on github, it's on stash and i want to avoid GUI and figure staff out through terminal.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your answer and valuable update. The lines of commands helped me the most. Theory makes it all confusing, whereas actually typing staff into terminal teaches me more than tutorials. PS. I didn't have command alias "co" for the "checkout" set up, but I resolve that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

**Downloading Project**

```
$ git clone https://link.git <folder-name>
$ git checkout -b feature/unit-tests-from-z
```

Those commands will download the repo into folder name, or into a folder named `link` if you don't provide one. The path is relative to your current working directory. Then you will checkout a *new* branch (that's what the `-b` flag signifies), also ending up on that branch.

The checkout command is really powerful. This is what you use to travel between historical commits, or to new branches. Any changes commited at any point in history can be seen using `git checkout [tag/hash/branch]`.

Then you can verify that you are on your new branch using:

```
$ git branch
```

**Adding Your Changes to the Branch**

When you are done with your changes, use:

```
$ git add .
```

The `.` signifies that you want to add all changed files relative from the current working directory. If you have removed files, then also use the `--ignore-removal` flag using the above command.

If you want more control over what's added, then use the following instead:

```
$ git add -p
```

It only works for changed files, however. Add new files with `$ git add /path/to/file`.

Don't just remove files the normal way when using git. Use:

```
$ git rm path/to/file
```

After adding all files, use:

```
$ git commit -m "A brief description about the changes you made."
```

If you dare using the default command line text editor, it is better to use:

```
$ git commit
```

**Uploading Your Changes**

How this is done depends on where the files are. If you have push rights to the repo where your branch is going, then you first need to add that repo (an https://link.git address won't work, as it's read only).

You do this using:

```
$ git remote add repo-name address-to-repo
```

After making sure you have a correct remote repository added to your project, use:

```
$ git push repo-name feature/unit-tests-from-z
```

Using this command will push your new branch to the repository in question.

Comment: What's unclear for me - is that change between branch that i've created and the one that I cloned. At the start, when I clone a remote branch "mainBranch", it also becomes my local branch. When I run "git branch" it tells me "mainBranch". I start adding changes to the project but they are done in the "mainBranch". At which point I can create my separate branch "feature/unit-tests-from-z" and how I can put my edited project to that new brunch and then upload it to the repo?

Comment: "Cloning a project" just another way of saying "downloading a project". If you already have the repository on your computer, you don't need to clone it. Use "git pull" to download all the commits made to your current branch. Working with new branches usually goes like this: 1. Fork (create a new branch of) the current branch. 2. Make changes to its files. 3. Add your changes. 4. Commit your changes. 5. Make sure the branch ends up somewhere useful. The order is important. If you make changes and commit them before the branching (forking), the changes ended up on the branch you were at instead.

Comment: 1. "If you already have the repo on your computer" - what does that mean? aren't they hosted on remote servers? 2. I don't understand the last step with uploading process. Why do we need to "add repo"? aren't they static and always "out there"? 3. In the command that you wrote - "repo-name" is the name of the repo from which I cloned my initial project? 4. if "https://" link won't work, what kind will work? Thank you again Emanuel you are helping a lot.

Comment: The main difference between git and other version control systems, such as svn, is that git is "distributed". This means, in reality, that everything you do is performed locally, on your computer. You download the entire repository (or at least the branch you are interested in), you make changes to it, create new branches, and then upload them back to origin repo (from which you downloaded the local one) or to some other repo. Did that clarify anything?

Comment: One of the main perks of distributed revision control is that you don't need to depend on some central server. Code can be shared directly between team members, and later be pushed to some server considered authoritative. A lot of control of the process is moved from the center to you.

Comment: Yes, it does clarify some things. So back to the commands, the uploading part. **1.** "repo-name"- how does it look like can you give an example? Is it just a name of the folder where .xcodeproj file is? **2.** What kind of a link to the repo will work? Can you give an example too please?

Comment: 1. http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote  2. http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols